# Windows script to check Informatica services running or not?

Tags: informatica

How to windows script that can check if informatica service is running or not, 
if not it should re-start and this script should run at windows startup .

Answer (score 0):

make a batch file and save this inside it

```
%INFA_HOME%/server/bin/infacmd.bat ping -dg localhost:6005
```

Assuming INFA_HOME is defined in your environment and you're using the default setup port of 6005. Informatica is usually created as as service under Windows running as a limited user account. It is set to start automatically and it will attempt to restart itself once if it fails. However you should look into why it failed starting rather than force starting it from a script.

Informatica's service is also known to take a minute or more in order to start so you might just want to be patient with it.